# Inserting data in KQL

Tags: azure, kql

I have a table that I created using KQL. Now I want to populate it by inserting values inside but could not get the exact syntax.
How to insert data in my table in KQL syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried your search engine? ;)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline

```
.ingest inline into table Purchases <|
Shoes,1000
Wide Shoes,50
"Coats, black",20
"Coats with ""quotes""",5
```

I assume that you know that single row ingests are usually not the way to [ingest data into Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/).

Comment: Thankyou. Thing is that I want to run/test my queries on custom data that I want to create (and populate), kind of a dummy one. I am not writing/ingesting my results to say an azure blob storage or anything like that, just want to fill in the tables so that I can run KQL Qeuries on them.

Comment: so? what is your question that is still open? If not, please accept